# Python консоль и странное поведение при IF

Tags: python

Хочу научится работать с условиями вввожу в консоли

```
>>> x = int(raw_input("Введите, пожалуйста, целое число: "))
```

Затем

```
>>> if x>0:
    print "Bla"
    elif x==0:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

И так при любом варианте, если даже место `elif` подсовываю `else`  он пишет мне эту ошибку. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Лишние четыре пробела перед elif?

Comment: Да вы правы. Добавьте ваш комментарий в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что во-первых проблема с табуляцией, а во-вторых - код нужно закончить, т.е. должно быть еще и else

Попробуй вот так

```
x = int(raw_input("Input figure: "))
```

Затем вот такой блок

```
 >>> if x>0:
    print 'Plus'
 elif x<-1:
    print 'Min'
 else:
    print 'Zero'
```

Еще все зависит от того, какую ты консоль используешь, т.е. например IDLE (Python GUI) - там автоматом проставляется табуляция кажется, т.е. если вводишь сразу первую строчку

```
 if....:
```

, а потом нажимаешь перевод на другую строку - то проставиться табуляция.
Как видишь в моем примере есть табуляция перед каждым print, она была автоматом прославлена, а вот табуляция перед else & elif - была наоборот убрана мной, т.е. backspace.

Comment: `else` не обязательно

Answer (score 2):

В синтаксисе питона (как, впрочем, и во многих других стайл-гайдах других языков) `elif` находится на одном уровне с `if`:

```
if foo:
    [блок кода с отступом]
elif foobar:
    [ещё блок кода]
else:
    [и ещё блок]
```

На интерпретатор это тоже распространяется, так что там четыре пробела лишние.

[image]